# How to implement aggregation functions for pandas groupby objects?

Tags: pandas, signature

Here's the setup for this question:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import collections as co
data = [['a',  1],
        ['a',  2],
        ['a',  3],
        ['a',  4],
        ['b',  5],
        ['b',  6],
        ['b',  7]]
varnames = tuple('PQ')
df = pd.DataFrame(co.OrderedDict([(varnames[i], [row[i] for row in data])
                                  for i in range(len(varnames))]))
gdf = df.groupby(df.ix[:, 0])
```

After evaluating the above, `df` looks like this:

```
>>> df
   P  Q
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  a  4
4  b  5
5  b  6
6  b  7
```

`gdf` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object associated with `df`, where the groups are determined by the values in the first column of `df`.

---

Now, watch this:

```
>>> gdf.aggregate(sum)
    Q
P
a  10
b  18
```

...but repeating the same thing after replacing `sum` with a *pass-through wrapper* for it, bombs:

```
>>> mysum = lambda *a, **k: sum(*a, **k)
>>> mysum(range(10)) == sum(range(10))
True
>>> gdf.aggregate(mysum)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/yt/.virtualenvs/yte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1699, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yt/.virtualenvs/yte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1757, in _aggregate_generic
    return self._aggregate_item_by_item(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yt/.virtualenvs/yte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1782, in _aggregate_item_by_item
    result[item] = colg.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yt/.virtualenvs/yte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1426, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yt/.virtualenvs/yte/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1508, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Here's a subtler (though probably related) issue.  Recall that the result of `gdf.aggregate(sum)` was a dataframe with a single column, `Q`.  Now, note the result below contains *two* columns, `P` and `Q`:

```
>>> import random as rn
>>> gdf.aggregate(lambda *a, **k: rn.random())
          P         Q
P
a  0.344457  0.344457
b  0.990507  0.990507
```

---

I have not been able to find anything in the documentation that would explain

1. why *should* `gdf.aggregate(mysum)` fail?  (IOW, does this failure agree with documented behavior, or is it a bug in pandas?)
2. why *should* `gdf.aggregate(lambda *a, **k: rn.random())` produce a two-column output while `gdf.aggregate(sum)` produce a one-column output?
3. what signatures (input and output) should an aggregation function `foo` have so that `gdf.aggregate(foo)` will return a table having only column `Q` (like the result of `gdf.aggregate(sum)`)?

Comment: I actually observe that `gdf.aggregate(mysum)` works the same as using `sum`, using pandas 0.14.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems all come down to the columns that are included in the GroupBy. I think you want to group by `P` and computed statistics on `Q`. To do that use

```
gdf = df.groupby('P')
```

instead of your method. Then any aggregations will not include the `P` column.

---

The `sum` in your function is Python's sum. Groupby.sum() is written in Cython and only acts on numeric dtypes. That's why you get the error about adding `ints` to `strs`.

Your other two questions are related to that. You're inputing two columns into `gdf.agg`, `P` and `Q` so you get two columns out for your `gdf.aggregate(lambda *a, **k: rn.random())`. `gdf.sum()` ignores the string column.